# How do I use drag events (dragover) in a #document embeded in an <object> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

An HTML file that I created is being displayed in an HTML object on the parent page.  I am creating some drag events on my page and they work fine when calling my html file directly.  But, when displayed inside an HTML `<object>` , the drag events (specifically trying dragover), do not fire, even though I see them listed in my event listeners.   During my troubleshooting, I noticed this is not an issue when showing the page inside an `<iframe>`.

I don't have the option to me to use `<iframe>`,  is there something I can do to allow the dragover event when displayed through the object tag?

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="mytest.html"></iframe>
    <object width="100%" height="100%" data="mytest.html"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dragovertest();
});

function dragovertest(){
  alert("popup");
}
```